# Likelihood ratio test for a subset of the parameters

Tags: log-likelihood

In the likelihood ratio parametric test, I was taught that the test is used when I want to test if the last q parameters are equal to some specific values or not.

Can I also use likelihood ratio test if I want to test if a subset of the parameters (for example: from parameter_3 to parameter_(n-2)) are equal to some specific values ? 
Or the test is only valid to test for the last q parameters ?

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like this belongs more to https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I would suggest trying your luck there if no one answers here :)

Comment: I’ve never known the parameters of a distribution to be “ordered”. Are the indices arbitrary?